# Laravel 5.2 Auth routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am having an issue with laravel routing.

I want to have routes like this:

```
/  - home page for unauthenticated users
/login  - login page
/register  - register page
/dashboard  - home page for authenticated users
```

After login i want user to be redirected to /dashboard, and if authenticated user goes to /   or any other unprotected route, i also want to redirect him to /dashboard.

My routes.php.

```
`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {  
    Route::auth(); 
    Route::get(‘/dashboard’, ‘DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');  
});`
```

This works, however if authenticated user goes to /  or any other unprotected route, i would like to redirect him to /dashboard. How can i make this work?

Comment: In your `HomeController@index` method, do a check and redirect the Auth user to dashboard. `Auth::check() ? return redirect()->url('/dashboard') : ''; `

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Comment: I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Laravel docs.

**Path Customization**

When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the / URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectTo property on the AuthController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

When a user is not successfully authenticated, they will be redirected back to the login form location automatically.

See more here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-routing

Answer (score 1):

you need to set ::

protected $redirectTo = '/home'

in the AuthController which will override the $redirectTo variable in the Trait used by AuthController.

u can also change redirectAfterLogout url in the same way.

!!Happy Coding.

Comment: I added $redirectTo = "/dashboard" and user gets redirected to /dashboard right after logged in which is fine. What i am asking here is if user once he is logged in goes to some public route i want to redirect him to /dashboard.

Comment: you can create a middleware for the same with logic as if Auth::check() redirect to dashboard..
And those middleware to the routes..

Answer (score 0):

In your `HomeController@index` method, do a check and redirect the Auth user to dashboard. `Auth::check() ? return redirect()->url('/dashboard') : '';`

Comment: If `/` is the only unprotected route handling this in `HomeController@index` would be fine, but there's no indication that this is the case, so your suggestion should be handled in middleware instead.

Comment: @Bogdan Yeah, that s true, i want to be able to redirect user from every route. How would i handle this in middleware?